# How to do a double series with Foreach of powershell

Tags: powershell

Here my code in powershell :

```
foreach ( $a in 2019..2020 ) 
{ 
   1..10| foreach {  
      $i="{0:00}" -f $_
      "$a_$i"
   }
}
```

I've got this output :

```
01
02
03
04
05
06
07
08
09
10
01
02
03
04
05
06
07
08
09
10
```

It seems that it's showing the `$i` variable values only.

How can I make it expand the `$a` variable as well, so that I get `2019_01`, `2019_02`, etc.?

Comment: You could just change your line `$i="{0:00}" -f $_` to `"{1}_{0:00}" -f $_,$a`, which will do the string formatting for you and remove the need for `$i`.

Comment: [js2010's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59080373/11025476) provides the clue for the posted symptom. Since `_` is a legal variable name character, PowerShell is trying to interpolate `$a_` rather than `$a`. Since `$a_` is undefined, `$null` is returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be careful with [string interpolation](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/variable-expansion-in-strings-and-here-strings/).

`"$a_$i"` should be  `"$($a)_$($i)"` or `"${a}_${i}"`.

Comment: ```"$a`_$i"``` with _escaped_ underscore should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

An underline can be part of a variable name:

```
$a_ = 'hi'
```

So you need some way to separate the $a.  You can also use curly braces.

```
foreach ( $a in 2019..2020 ) 
{ 
   1..10| foreach {  
      $i="{0:00}" -f $_
      "${a}_$i"
   }
}
```